# Model Design and AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I recently came across a project that has some models containing several properties that are updated through automatic calculations.

For example: Product contains the properties, quantity and weight and then contains a property 'TotalWeight' that performs the calculation (quantity x weight)

All calculations are processed in the business (accessed through api) (whether in .NET or Java or any other technology)

My question basically is. To show the calculations right after the property changes in the same screen, i need to replicate the calculations in AngularJS´s controllers or is correct I send all model data to the server to perform the "update calculations" every time my model changes?

Comment: I think it would be better to do ajax request and do calculations on the server to avoid code duplication. But if it is an unnecessary overhead, the logic is not so complex and not dependent on business variables, it would be faster for the end user if you re-implement the calculation logic in JS.

Comment: That would depend on the complexity of your calculations and the actual need to avoid any latency when showing the results. Its not possible to answer that question without looking at the specific requirements of your project.

Comment: The calculations are quite complex... some of them are tax calculation from brazil taxes between states (ICMS) and it has several rules. So i think i will make those requests in server... I am just thinking what is the best way to do this.